# adapter showing list in reverse order load earlier message in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi I want to merge the previous records to merge with current data in the cardview using load earlier message button.everything working fine but the data is collasped.the new data is top most order,first older data comes under the new datas,and second older data comes under the first older data and so on.I want to load the adapter in the reverse order. this is my code.Each page consist of 30 records.

```
  multipleRowRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                load.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        t=t+1;

                        newdata(t);
                        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });
            } else {
                load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });



  public void newdata(int t) {
     page= String.valueOf(t);
  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+page,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject homeobj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject insteller  = homeobj.getJSONObject("INSTELLAR");
                        status = insteller.getString("STATUS");

                        if(status.equals("success")) {
                            JSONArray data = insteller.getJSONArray("DATA");
                            for(int i=data.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
                                // msg = jsonObject.getString("MSG").toString();

                                typee=jsonObject.getString("TYPE").toString();
                                if(typee.equals("1"))
                                {
                                    type    = AppConstant.FIRST_ROW;
                                    content =  jsonObject.getString("MSG").toString();
                                    date     =  jsonObject.getString("DATE").toString();
                                    img = jsonObject.getString("IMAGE").toString();

                                }
                                else {


                                    type = AppConstant.OTHER_ROW;
                                    content = jsonObject.getString("MSG").toString();
                                    date = jsonObject.getString("DATE").toString();
                                    img = jsonObject.getString("IMAGE").toString();
                                }

                                multipleRowRecyclerView.setAdapter(multipleRowAdapter);
                                multipleRowModelList.add(new MultipleRowModel(type, content, date, img));
                                multipleRowRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(multipleRowModelList.size()-1);
                            }


                            multipleRowRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(multipleRowModelList.size()-30);



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("clientid", KEY_ClientID);
            params.put("adminid", KEY_ADMINID);
            params.put("userid", KEY_USERID);
            params.put("pageno", page);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your MultipleRowModel class?

I think you can use Queue and show record from this Queue.
like this,

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 class GenQueue<E> {
    private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
    public void enqueue(E item) {
       list.addLast(item);
    }
    public E dequeue() {
       return list.poll();
    }
    public boolean hasItems() {
       return !list.isEmpty();
    }
    public int size() {
       return list.size();
    }
    public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {
       while (q.hasItems())
          list.addLast(q.dequeue());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pamitha,shall i give adapter class

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void newdata(int t) {
     page= String.valueOf(t);
    pos=+30;
  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+page,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject homeobj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject insteller  = homeobj.getJSONObject("INSTELLAR");
                        status = insteller.getString("STATUS");

                        if(status.equals("success")) {
                            JSONArray data = insteller.getJSONArray("DATA");
                            for(int i=data.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
                                // msg = jsonObject.getString("MSG").toString();

                                typee=jsonObject.getString("TYPE").toString();
                                if(typee.equals("1"))
                                {
                                    type    = AppConstant.FIRST_ROW;
                                    content =  jsonObject.getString("MSG").toString();
                                    date     =  jsonObject.getString("DATE").toString();
                                    img = jsonObject.getString("IMAGE").toString();

                                }
                                else {


                                    type = AppConstant.OTHER_ROW;
                                    content = jsonObject.getString("MSG").toString();
                                    date = jsonObject.getString("DATE").toString();
                                    img = jsonObject.getString("IMAGE").toString();
                                }

                                multipleRowRecyclerView.setAdapter(multipleRowAdapter);
                                multipleRowModelList.add(0,new MultipleRowModel(type, content, date, img));
                               }


                              multipleRowRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(multipleRowModelList.size()-pos);



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("clientid", KEY_ClientID);
            params.put("adminid", KEY_ADMINID);
            params.put("userid", KEY_USERID);
            params.put("pageno", page);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```